# How to uninstall Paint on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview, microsoft-paint

In previous versions of Windows I believe Paint could be disabled in `Programs and Features->Turn Windows features on or off`, however in Windows 10 I don't see Paint in there.

How do I get this piece of software off my computer?

Comment: You were never able to uninstall Paint in any Windows version > Windows XP.

Comment: Why would one do this?

Comment: @Herb Because 'Paint' appears above 'Paint.net' when going to the start menu and typing 'Paint' to open your image editor. It's not a great reason, but it's why I searched for this answer.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys: makes sense. Thx.

Comment: You can remove the shortcut to Paint from Start menu.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys just search for Paint.Net a few times and it'll appear before Paint. No need to uninstall Paint

Answer (score 3):

Type "paint" in the start menu, then right-click the Paint app, then choose goto file location. This will open the Explorer in the folder where the link to MS Paint is located. Just delete the link and you won't get bother with MS Paint when searching for "paint" anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You could rename / remove mspaint.exe from C:\Windows\System32
When you open a file extension linked to MSPaint it will throw an error message and you will be asked to chose a new default program.

Or you could just link the file extensions you want to your editor of choice:
right-click file, select Open With and tick 'always open with this program') mspaint.exe is like 5MB so it's not taking up much space.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but since Windows 10 20H1 (2004) it's possible to uninstall the classic Paint. The steps are:

1. Go to Settings and click on Apps & features.
2. Locate the link Optional features and click on it.
3. It will display a list of programs. Search through the list until you find Microsoft Paint.
4. Finally, click on the uninstall button.